# Why do tabs line up differently in different text editors?

Tags: tabs, formatting, text-editor, spaces

I keep running across a problem where source code that uses tabs to line up key/value assignments is displayed differently in different editors.

For instance, a file on Github in both the [highlighted](https://github.com/iandunn/WordPress-Plugin-Skeleton/blob/master/classes/wpps-cpt-example.php) and [raw](https://raw.github.com/iandunn/WordPress-Plugin-Skeleton/master/classes/wpps-cpt-example.php) versions shows the `$labels` array at line `55` with mis-aligned spacing. It also looks that way in Notepad.

But, that same file, copied into Aptana or Notepad++ will display the values lined up perfectly.

Why does that happen, and is it possible to create the file in such a way that it will be displayed correctly across all editors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your settings in each editor, they will each use a different number of spaces for a tab.

Some use 2, some use 3, some use 4, and some use 6. You can see by highlighting one of the tabs in github, the tab takes up 8 spaces.

This should be adjustable in the editor.

If you create a file in an editor that uses a particular number of spaces, and view it in an editor that uses a different number of spaces, things will look different.

There has always been a debate about whether to use spaces or tabs for indentation. It's a personal preference thing, but using spaces rather than tabs will prevent this issue.

You should be able to set your editor to use spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: But regardless of whether a tab is defined as 2 spaces, or 4, or 8, there are still the same number of tabs present, so I would expect that all the values would still be lined up, and that the only difference would be how many spaces were between the keys and values. Why does the length of a tab cause the values to no longer line up?

Comment: This is because the tab doesn't start in the same column on every line.

Comment: But the first tab is always a variable length, right? Assuming tabs are 8 spaces, then if the cursor is at position 2 on the line, and you hit tab, it would be 6 spaces long, then all the following tabs would be 8 spaces. If you were at position 7, then the tab would be 1 space long and the following tabs would be 8 spaces. So, the first tab always takes you to the next column marker. I would think at that point they'd all be lined up, regardless of how long the tabs are.

Comment: Assume columns start at 1. If you're at column 3 & you were using 4 space tabs, & hit tab twice it would take you to column 9. If you had another line and were at column 6 & pressed tab, you would be at column 9 also. So the two lines would line up. If you then switched editor to one that used 8 space tabs, the first line would have two tabs from column 3, taking you to column 17, and the second line would still line up to column 9. Thus the two lines look uneven.